# Laravel - override the route get method for a model

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have 2 models, Foo and Bar. Both are using a slugs for keys.

I have a route setup like this `Route::get('{foo}/{bar}', 'Object\BarController@index');`

So I can go to something like `abc/xyz`.

My database looks like this:

```
Foo
    - 1, abc
    - 2, def

Bar
    - xyz, 1
    - xyz, 2
```

As you can see, Bar references a row in Foo.

Foo and Bar's models have their relationship setup like so: Foo hasMany Bar and Bar belongsTo Foo.

All of this is working nicely, however, when I go to the url `abc/xyz` or `def/xyz` I don't get the correct item in Bar. I only get the first row, regardless of which Foo I have in the route.

I would like to solve this by changing the way Laravel automatically gets the data from the DB. How would I go about this? Can I add a method in the Bar model that changes the default get method for a route with parameters?

Comment: dont know what you mean by 'not getting the correct item in Bar ...regardless of which Foo'

Comment: since you have 2 xyz values in the bar table and you use these as slugs, wouldn't it be better to have them be unique?

Comment: I don't want the slug to be unique. The rows are unique by the combination of the Foo id and Bar slug.

Comment: @lagbox if I go to the url `abc/xyz` I should get the 1st item in the Bar table. If I go to the url `def/xyz` I should get the 2nd item in the Bar table. The problem is that both urls get the 1st item.

Comment: all bindings are separate things, they have no relationship to one another. see if you can maybe do an explicit binding where you can define your own resolver that takes into account the other 'segments'/'bindings' when it resolves ... ref the route model binding docs